# Window (Geary) always open maximized?

Tags: pantheon-mail, window-manager

Always when I open Geary it automatically maximize.
I looked into settings in dconf tools `org.yorba.geary window-maximize` is not checked.

Anybody who knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature ;)
elementary OS automatically maximizes every starting window that is bigger than 70% of your screen size.
You can turn off this behaviour by running the following command in your terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize false
```

BTW: It will be disabled by default in the next release of elementary OS.